# iOS - get the url of server served files

Tags: ios

I set up a server inside an app I'm writing, and I set the server to serve some files in a directory. I want to get the URL of those files. What is the correct format for those files? Is it http://{IP address of the phone}/{Directory Path}/{filename}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please don't duplicate questions...**

Your question is not so well structured but let's see.

If you have a webserver on your app, your ip will be

```
http://127.0.0.0:port(where the webserver is running)/and/so/on.
```

More, if you also want the localserver be accessible from other device on the same network you need the current wifi ip.

Comment: I salute you sir! I asked two questions because in my first one I mentioned a specific project and chromecast and I was afraid that that might scare people and no one would answer my question. I should have edited that question instead of asking a new one. I'm sorry about the duplicate.